# Improve CSV file write speed

Tags: python, performance, csv

The code below works just fine. I'm wondering is there any way to improve the write speed of it. As it would currently take from 12 to 20 seconds to write the .csv file.

```
import csv
import os

data = [...1000 item list, where each item is a dictionary with 8 values...]

for candle in data:
        if os.path.isfile('data'+os.sep+i+os.sep+coin_symbol+'.csv'):
            H = []
            H.append(candle['timestamp'])
            H.append(candle['open'])
            H.append(candle['close'])
            H.append(candle['min'])
            H.append(candle['max'])
            H.append(candle['volume'])
            H.append(candle['volumeQuote'])

            with open('data'+os.sep+i+os.sep+coin_symbol+'.csv', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                csvwriter.writerow(H)
        else: 

                H = []
                H.append('TimeStamp')
                H.append('Open')
                H.append('Close')
                H.append('Min')
                H.append('Max')
                H.append('Volume')
                H.append('VolumeQuote')



                with open('data'+os.sep+i+os.sep+coin_symbol+'.csv', 'w', newline="") as csvfile:
                    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                    csvwriter.writerow(H)
                H = []
                H.append(candle['timestamp'])
                H.append(candle['open'])
                H.append(candle['close'])
                H.append(candle['min'])
                H.append(candle['max'])
                H.append(candle['volume'])
                H.append(candle['volumeQuote'])

                with open('data'+os.sep+i+os.sep+coin_symbol+'.csv', 'a', newline="") as csvfile:
                    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                    csvwriter.writerow(H)
```

For the Else statement, is there any way to write it differently?

Comment: Why are you re-opening the file, creatinga writer object,  over and over again in a loop? I would start by bringing that out of the loop...

Comment: You can use `os.path.join(...)` - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how would that look like? 

the line "with open(...)" would come above the loop and the rest of if, would stay where it is, but be in the same indentation as H.append?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach avoids reopening your output file. It also makes use of a `DictWriter` as `data` is already a dictionary:

```
import os
import csv


filename = os.path.join('data', i, coin_symbol + '.csv')
mode = 'a' if os.path.isfile(filename) else 'w'

fieldnames = ['timestamp', 'open', 'close', 'min', 'max', 'volume', 'volumeQuote']
header = ['TimeStamp', 'Open', 'Close', 'Min', 'Max', 'Volume', 'VolumeQuote']

with open(filename, mode, newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    if mode == 'w':
        csv_output.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, header)))

    for row in data:
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

`os.path.join()` is a better approach than trying to add `os.sep`.